# Getting "TypeError: Dropdown is not a function" when trying to use a class in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I'm getting "TypeError: Dropdown is not a function when trying to do the following:

```
/*
 * Dropdown.js
 */

var __container;

function Dropdown(el) {
   __container = el;
}

Dropdown.prototype = {
   constructor: Dropdown,

   getOptions: function() { return __container.element.all(by.css('option')); },

   // my other prototype methods
}
```

--

```
/*
 * PageObject.js
 */

var Dropdown = require('Dropdown');

var PageObject() {}

PageObject.prototype = {
   constructor: PageObject,

   myDd: new Dropdown(element(by.css('select')),

   //my other prototype methods which do work
};
```

--

```
/*
 * spec.js
 */

var PageObject = require('PageObject');

describe('Test my page', function() {
   it('should test the dropdown', function() {
      browser.get(mypage);
      var pageObject = new PageObject();
      expect(pageObject.myDd.getOptions().isPresent()).toBe(true);
   });
});
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur? I would guess at `myDd: new Dropdown(element(by.css('select')),`, but maybe you could add this piece of potentially important information.

Comment: How do you export Dropdown? In other words, how does `require` know where to find it? Shouldn't you do something with `define` or `exports`? Do you just use RequireJS? Is the `require` you use part of another framework or library you use? Which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @11684 mentioned - you've forgot to export your Dropdown and PageObject classes and `require('Dropdown');` returns undefined. Protractor is run on node.js so you need to fill the gaps about CommonJS modules. Also if you want to require modules which are not installed with npm you have to target them using relative paths so rather than

```
var PageObject = require('PageObject');
```

you'd need to do something like

```
var PageObject = require('./pages/PageObject');
var Dropdown = require('../helpers/Dropdown');
```

etc.

and to export a module in node environment using commonJS modules you need to either export them as set of properties/methods set on the exports object or you can assign your constructor directly to it so it's available directly on the required module

```
// in Dropdown
module.exports = Dropdown;

// in PageObject
module.exports = PageObject;
```

If you plan to use more of node.js in your testing you should read bit more about working with commonJS modules https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html and on node.js itself in general. Would recommend checking out what from ES6 you can use already http://node.green/ to make your tests more organised and readable as well

Comment: /me bangs head against wall.  Surely I didn't do tha... yep, I did. I have it for PageObject, but forgot it for Dropdown. Thanks for the other info, too. I'll check it out.

Comment: Cheers Machtyn, glad to be of help.